# Updated terminal ZSH, python modules now missing/inaccessible

Tags: python, command-line, terminal, zsh

Received this notification when trying to run python code:
[image]

Updated and tried to run that same code:

[image]

This has never happened before. I run 'python --version' and it says 3.7. If I build scripts in Sublime they run, but that build is tethered to Anaconda. Any suggestions on how to fix this so I can run my scripts in terminal?

Comment: All it's telling you is that the default shell in Catalina (I'm assuming you upgraded recently) is intended to be zsh instead of bash and it wants you to change it. It shouldn't have actually changed anything, although if you were using a non-standard Python (e.g. from homebrew) it may have altered your PATH when you upgraded, meaning packages installed with the other Python will not be available. N.B. you can turn off the warning by putting `export BASH_SILENCE_DEPRECATION_WARNING=1` in your profile or .bashrc

Comment: See [this q/a on askdifferent.se](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/387102/did-the-shell-terminal-change-in-catalina) for example.

Comment: Based on your prompt, it appears the virtual environment containing `requests` is not active. Perhaps you had something like `. base/bin/activate` in your `.bash_profile`, which is not in your `.zsh_profile`.